# How to automate the migration of core functionalities from core project to its clone projects

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have one core project(product) in angular. I maintain its repository on github. Every time a new client comes for this product, we create a clone of core project and add customization's according to the client requirements.

Now the problem is, whenever there is some code change in the components of core project we have to manually copy those changes to the clone projects. Lets say we have 100 projects then we have to copy a small code change to 100 projects. Is there any way I can automate this, like every time there is some change in the components of core project, it will get automatically migrated to the clone projects?

I checked the working of npm libraries. It loads all the dependencies in node_modules. I am not sure if I can achieve my objective using this. But please let me know if its possible using npm and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution I can think to what you want to achieve, is to create a shared angular Module or an [angular 6 library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries), from your core project and publish it. For every new client's angular project, Import your core angular library in it and use it. That way you can update your core library anytime and you would only need to run npm update on all the projects that uses the library

And ofcourse you will need to change the architecture of your core project a bit in order to make it a re-usable library. You will need to create generic re-usable components, directives, services, pipes etc and export it.

Also, there are limitations to what changes you can do in the core library that would only require 'npm update' in the other projects to reflect the change

Comment: Thanks Bilal for your answer. Project structure is module based. Is it possible to create libraries  of modules instead of creating a library of whole project and achieve the same objective?

Comment: yes! you can create as many modules in a single library and as many libraries as you want. and you can also control exactly what you want this library to export. You might want to create multiple modules in the library to be used internally but expose only one central module for other projects to use. Refer to angular 6's Library documentation

Comment: Hi Bilal, Is there any functionality in git by which I can keep all the clone projects in sync? Eg. when any code changes are merged in the master of core project then same changes will be merged with other cloned projects automatically.